# How does a 4 electrode set up eliminate interference impedance

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, impedance

[image: Picture of the circuit system]

Looking at the impedance of this circuit, how here is the impedance isolated of B and the total impedance not affected by the impedance of the electrodes (e).

Answer (score 2):

It is affected by 'e' in the V path (cold load B with parallel resistance), but that can generally be made negligible -- e.g. in a voltmeter, input impedance is 10 M ohm or 'infinite' which would not affect a low impedance B measurement.  In case it does, you can make a measurement with 'B' open ciruit, and subtract that from the measurement with B present. This is called de-embedding.

'e' in the 'I' path is in series with the stimulus (I), so has no effect.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the wires and electrodes have impedance that will develop a potential difference proportional to the current flowing through them. So if you measure the voltage across the element at the current source I, what you are really measuring is the voltage across the device under test (DUT) *less* the voltages dropped (lost) across each of the electrodes and and their wires (the outer loop in your diagram).

It may seem like the 4-wire "Kelvin Connection" solution also suffers from this problem, in that we are still measuring the voltage across the element using long wires and imperfect electrodes, but the current flowing through these "sense" wires/electrodes (the inner loop in your diagram) is far, far lower than the current in the outer loop. That's because (presumably) the voltmeter in the inner loop draws negligible current.

This means that the voltmeter reading on the inner loop will be much closer to the actual potential difference across the DUT than any potential difference reading taken across the current source.

Answer (score 1):

Since a constant current is supplied via the two outer electrodes, the impedances \$\text e\$ of those electrodes do not affect the voltage across B, it only increases the voltage that the constant current source must supply in order to maintain the constant current.

If we assume the voltage measurement instrument has an input impedance that is much higher than \$2\cdot \text e\$, then the impedances of the inner electrodes do not affect the voltage reading significantly.

This is called a ["Kelvin" connection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four-terminal_sensing), after William Thomsom.